# Include a Searchbox in a Django Crispy Forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am using the Django Crispy forms and a Foreignkey field. I am using a foreignkey to get a list of all contacts. When creating a new form, I`ve got a very long list of contact to choose from. What I would like to do is to search the contact in a searchbox. At the moment, I can not use this feature as there are too many contacts to search. Is there a way to add a search box in the forms html? What would be the django crispy forms field to modify?

**forms.py**

```
class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
        class Meta:
            model = Invoice
            fields = ['name','contact','company','terms','due_date','invoice_date','notes','draft']  
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(InvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_tag = True
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Row(
                    Column('name', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                    Column('contact', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                    Column('company', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                    css_class='form-row'
                ),
                Row(
                    Column('terms', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                    Column('due_date', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                    Column('invoice_date', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                    css_class='form-row'
                ),            
                Fieldset('Add lines',Formset('lines')),
                Row(                               
                    css_class='form-row'
                ),
                Row(
                    Column('notes', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                    Column('draft', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                    css_class='form-row'
                ),
                Div(               
                    HTML("<br>"),
                    ButtonHolder(Submit('submit', 'Save')),
                    css_class='float-right',               
                    ),
                Div(               
                    HTML("<br>"),
                    )
                  
                )
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've used two solutions for this problem:

- https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/
- I used (for some internal project) the admin widget (Horizontal Filter?). It doesn't look very nice but it might do the job... but it feels a bit hacky

I cannot think of a way to do it just using django-crispy-forms.